# No metadata found. There is more than once class-validator version installed probably. You need to flatten your dependencies

Tags: node.js, typescript, class-validator

when I run this command `curl -vd '{"NickName":"Marry","Password":"pwd"}' -H "Content-type: application/json"  http://127.0.0.1:3000/signin`,  I got 
`No metadata found. There is more than once class-validator version installed probably. You need to flatten your dependencies.` printed on Server side, and `validate` did not perform correctly.
Before all this, I `npm install` some dependencies:

```
npm install --save routing-controllers
npm install --save class-transformer
npm install --save class-validator
```

Could Somebody help? How can I fix this?Thanks!

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Length } from 'class-validator';
import * as ErrorCode from '../error/errorcode'

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    @Column({
        name: "id"
    })
    Id?: number;

    @Column({
        name: "nickname"
    })
    @Length(1, 20, {
        message: "NickName must be 1 to 20 characters",
        context: {
            errorCode: ErrorCode.ParamLengthNotInRange
        }
    })
    Nickname: string;

    @Column({
        name: "password"
    })
    @Length(6,20)
    Password: string;

    //constructor(input : { Id : number , Nickname: string, Password: string}){
    constructor(input : { Nickname: string, Password: string}){
        //this.Id = input.Id;
        this.Nickname = input.Nickname;
        this.Password = input.Password;
    }

}
```

```
import { JsonController, Post, Body, Req } from "routing-controllers";
import { validate, ValidationError } from 'class-validator';
import {User} from '../entity'

@JsonController()
export class UserController {

    @Post('/signin')
    async signin(@Body() user: User) {
        const errors: ValidationError[] = await validate(user)
        if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
            console.log(errors[0].contexts!['Length'].errorCode)
        }
        console.log(user)
        return 'this is signin'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if you have more versions of `class-validator` installed by doing:

```
npm ls class-validator
```

In my case I was using `type-graphql` and found that `type-graphql` was also installing an earlier version of `class-validator`. So I just downgraded the one in package.json to the earlier version to make them match then did a fresh install and the message disappeared.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same message. Update of `class-validator` from 0.12.2 to 0.13.1 solved it.